# How to filter list 1 without elements of list 2

Tags: erlang

What is the best way to create a new list based on `List1` without elements of `List2`?

```
List1 = ["Candy", "Brandy", "Sandy", "Lady", "Baby", "Shady"].
List2 = ["Sandy", "Shady", "Candy", "Sandy"].
```

The contents of the new list should be:

```
List3 = ["Brandy", "Lady", "Baby"].
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Currently, the best way to do this is to use a module that handles sets, such as [ordsets](http://erlang.org/doc/man/ordsets.html):

```
> ordsets:subtract(ordsets:from_list(List1), ordsets:from_list(List2)).
["Baby","Brandy","Lady"]
```

If you're using Erlang/OTP 22 or later (due to be released in June 2019), the best way is using the `--` operator:

```
> List3 = List1 -- List2.
["Brandy","Lady","Baby"]
```

The runtime complexity of this operation is O(n log n) starting in Erlang/OTP 22, but in earlier Erlang versions, the runtime complexity of this operation is O(n*m), so it would perform very badly if both lists are very long.

---

See [the Retired Myths chapter in the Erlang Efficiency Guide](http://erlang.org/doc/efficiency_guide/retired_myths.html#myth--list-subtraction-------operator--is-slow):

> ## 12.3  Myth: List subtraction ("--" operator) is slow
>
> List subtraction used to have a run-time complexity proportional to the product of the length of its operands, so it was extremely slow when both lists were long.
>
> As of OTP 22 the run-time complexity is "n log n" and the operation will complete quickly even when both lists are very long. In fact, it is faster and uses less memory than the commonly used workaround to convert both lists to ordered sets before subtracting them with `ordsets:subtract/2`.

Comment: Both lists will be no longer than 5-10 elements.Thank you for answer